# Is it possible to get PDF Document security using exiftool

Tags: pdf, xmp, exiftool

I want to extract PDF document security settings, like content copying, printing, etc.
Is it possible to use exiftool.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried. For example, did you read exiftool's list of features or user manual? Did you try for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean because there may be various ways to specify security settings.  If the document is signed, ExifTool will report all of the usage rights.  For example:

Signing Date                    : 2011:05:24 09:48:57+02:00
Signing Authority               : ARE Acrobat Product v8.0 P23 0002337
Document Usage Rights           : FullSave
Form Usage Rights               : Add, FillIn, Delete, SubmitStandalone
Signature Usage Rights          : Modify

The thing to do is to try it yourself to see if it reports the settings that you are interested in.  If not, post a feature request and some sample PDF's in the [ExifTool Forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/)